# Transfer .htacces to web.config, 302 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web.config-transform

How to translate this .htaccess to web.config file to work properly, and is it right name web.config of that file?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mynedomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is in `web.config` file that you have to do it.

You can add a `rewrite` block into it for your rule

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to new domain" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mynedomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

In your htaccess code, you have a `302` redirect (that's why i used `Found` in the rule).
If you want instead a `301` redirect, replace `Found` by `Permanent` in the action tag of the rule.